# how to put focus back on textbox which fails validation ,inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have below `textbox` inside `itemtemplate of gridview.`.problem is when i click on `edit button of gridview`,and if i enter invalid value in `textbox` according to validation logic, `focus of textbox is lost` when i click on `update button`..if i am at 30est row focus went to top most row..how to prevent focus..

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tbattendence"  Width="40px" runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("attendence") %>' onkeydown = "return (event.keyCode!=13);">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbattendence"
                ErrorMessage="Attended Attendence is required!"  Display="Dynamic"  ValidationGroup="bottom" 
               ForeColor="#6600FF">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

              <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="Attended Attendence must be Lesser!"
                                ControlToValidate="tbattendence" ControlToCompare="tbcutoff"  
                                Display="Dynamic" Operator="LessThanEqual" Type="Integer" ValidationGroup="bottom">*</asp:CompareValidator>
```

Comment: Add SetFocusOnError="true" Property in your Validator Controls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
SetFocusOnError="true"
```

to your validation controls like this

```
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" SetFocusOnError="true" ...
```